# Start IPython kernel from within Python script

Tags: ipython

Say I have the following file `t.py`:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = get_ipython()
    if ip is not None:
        print('Found IPython')
```

Here's what happens if I run it, with both `Python` and `IPython`:

```
% python t.py
% ipython t.py 
Found IPython
```

Note that, only when running it with `ipython`, is `get_ipython()` not None.

Is there a way to start an IPython kernel from within the script, so that even if I run it as `python t.py`, then `get_ipython()` will not be None?

Comment: Did you try calling `IPython.start_kernel()`?

Comment: yes, and got ```
  warn("The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0."
NOTE: When using the `ipython kernel` entry point, Ctrl-C will not work.
To exit, you will have to explicitly quit this process, by either sending
"quit" from a client, or using Ctrl-\ in UNIX-like environments.
To read more about this, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2049
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-15293.json
```

Answer (score 4):

IPython starts new interactive shell, i.e. your code will be suspended until IPython shell is terminated.

You can have a launcher in a separate file, `launcher.py`:

```py
import IPython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IPython.start_ipython(['t.py'])
```

```sh
% python launcher.py
Found IPython
```

For other options of embedding IPython see the docs https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though - suppose `t.py` ends with `sys.exit(1)`. Then, running `python t.py` will work without exceptions, and the return code will be 1, while `python launcher.py` will through a `SystemExit` error and show a traceback. Could launcher.py preserve the exit code of `t.py`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity You can capture `SystemExit` exception which has `code` value, then `sys.exit` with that value.

Comment: Do you mean to put that in `launcher.py`? I've tried, and it's not working for me

Comment: Yes, you can capture `SystemExit` and return its code in `launcher.py`, but `t.py` will still print stack trace.